# DF able to compare integer YYYYMMDD to String YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've created a data factory pipeline process to move daily files from an sftp to a blob storage. It uses a get Metadata activity to get the file list.

[image]

r/AZURE - DF able to compare integer YYYYMMDD to String YYYY-MM-DD
Here's an example output from GetFileList:

```
 {  "childItems": [         
{           
"name": "flash_export_20240227110246.csv",          
"type": "File"  
},
```

I then have a Filter activity that uses the naming format of the file _YYYYMMDDTime to compare to the date 7 days ago to get a filtered list of the files with a name in the last 7 days as below:

```
{
    "items": "@activity('GetFileList').output.childItems",
    "condition": "@greaterOrEquals(substring(item().name,13,8),substring(subtractFromTime(utcnow(), 7, 'Day'), 0, 10))"
}
```

The input from substring(item().name,13,8) will give 20240227 for example but subtractFromTime(utcnow(), 7, 'Day'), 0, 10) will give 2024-02-23 so I'm surprised it the greaterOrEquals is actually able to compare them?

I only realised after I'd built the process and it was working based on some other work we had and I'm scratching my head as to why it actually works and returns the last 7 files to me. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

I would expect this to fail and require some kind of replace(substring(subtractFromTime(utcnow(), 7, 'Day'), 0, 10),'-','') to be required.

Answer (score 0):

The above expression is wrong for the given requirement. It will give `True` for the smaller dates as well.

For sample, I am checking for the `flash_export_20240127110246.csv` with same expression.

```
@greaterOrEquals(substring('flash_export_20240127110246.csv',13,8),substring(subtractFromTime(utcnow(), 7, 'Day'), 0, 10))
```

[image]

Here, it will compare the strings `20240127` and `2024-02-27` and you can see it is giving `true` for these values as well which is wrong result.

[image]

Here, the reason for this behavior is `greaterOrEquals()` will give the results for the strings as well. For the above example, it is comparing `20240127` and `2024-02-27` as strings and the first value will be greater than the second in terms of string. So, it is giving `true` as a result.

To achieve your requirement, you need to use the second expression involving `replace` of `-`. You can compare the integers as well like bellow expression.

```
@greaterOrEquals(int(substring('flash_export_20240127110246.csv',13,8)),int(replace(substring(subtractFromTime(utcnow(), 7, 'Day'), 0, 10),'-','')))
```

Comment: Hi, that all makes sense to me other than 20240127 being greater than 2024-02-27 as a string? But looking at the output from today from the filter it seems to work:
`{
 "ItemsCount": 368,
 "FilteredItemsCount": 7,
 "Value": [
  {
   "name": "flash_export_20240227110513.csv",
   "type": "File"
  },
....
  {
   "name": "flash_export_20240304110606.csv",
   "type": "File"
  }
 ]
}`

Comment: Ok, what is the result when you try the above second expression? Is it resulting the same?

Comment: It did produce the exact same result until today, this morning the filter brought back this:
`{
 "ItemsCount": 369,
 "FilteredItemsCount": 65,
 "Value": [
  {
   "name": "flash_export_20240101110309.csv",
   "type": "File"
  },......
  {
   "name": "flash_export_20240305110523.csv",
   "type": "File"
  }
 ]
}`
So 20240101 now evaluates as greater than 2024-02-27, I'm going to make the change and it's good to know that this logic doesn't work as I would have expected. I do wander why from today it now returns 65 items instead of the usual 7 which it has been doing for weeks.

Comment: The second expression is the correct one In my opinion because it is comparing the integers of dates. check your filter array with a python code with same logic and see the correct result.